# Why does Xcode 10 Crash?

Tags: xcode, xcode10

I am trying to open a project that I created using Xcode 9 with Xcode 10 which I just downloaded yesterday. When I open the project Xcode crashes every time. I am able to create new projects and open others, but this one particular project crashes Xcode every time, regardless of the way I try to open it.

In researching this issue I have done the following in an effort to resolve the problem:

- Rebooted √
- Reinstall Xcode √
- Delete the DerivedData folder √

The error message in the Xcode quite unexpectedly popup says:

> UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSGenericException): The window has been marked as
>   needing another Layout Window pass, but it has already had more Layout
>   Window passes than there are views in the window.

One other clue, that may or may not be related. I searched through the system log and came across this which was recorded at the same time as the crash:

> Failed to bootstrap path: path =
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/XPCServices/com.apple.dt.Xcode.SymbolicateXPCService.xpc,
>   error = 129: The service was superseded by a later version

I have put a lot of work into this project and would really like to be able to save it. Thanks.

Comment: "I have put a lot of work into this project and would really like to be able to save it." No problem. Open the project in Xcode 9. And file a bug report with Apple, including your crash logs and copy of your project.

Comment: Definitely not a quick win, but a path forward. Thanks.

Comment: Don’t forget to file that bug. If Xcode crashes, Apple wants to know all about it!

Comment: Will do. Thank you.

Comment: Matt. I downloaded Xcode 9.4 and was able to open my project. I then closed it out and launched Xcode 10 and was able to open the project without crashing. Problem solved. Many thanks.

Comment: Wow, excellent! Congratulations. — so what now? You should either delete this question or, even better, answer it yourself reporting that. It could help others who encounter the same or similar issue!

Answer (score 1):

Per Matt's suggestion, I downloaded Xcode 9.4 and was able to open the problematic project. It opened and I was able to build and run the project. I then closed it out and opened Xcode 10. I was then able to open the project, update it to Swift 4.2 and then build and run the project. Problem solved.